# Failing to populate Select element using RequestScoped bean?

Tags: jsf, initialization, selectonemenu

I've been struggling with a task that seemed to be very simple, but somehow I can't see a way to solve it without using some pretty hacky code - which I really want to avoid.

The problem itself has been reduced to a very simple task: I have a project with a single page containing a form, where I have to type a non-empty username and use a select element (h:selectOneMenu) to choose one "user group" for this user. This is submitted to a RequestScoped bean that I have (this is also the only bean I have in the project). Only validation rule (to simplify my explanation) is: the "username" field cannot be empty.

Here's my page's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{userManagementBean.initializeGroupsList()}" type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>


    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="fieldUsername" value="#{userManagementBean.user.username}" p:placeholder="Username" required="true" />
        <h:message for="fieldUsername"/>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="fieldGroup" value="#{userManagementBean.usergroup_id}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Please, select a group" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{userManagementBean.groupsList}" var="curGroup" itemLabel="#{curGroup.groupName}" itemValue="#{curGroup.id}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:message for="fieldGroup"/>

        <h:commandButton action="#{userManagementBean.submitValues()}" value="Submit data" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And here's the bean's code, which initializes a list containing the elements of the select box:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

....

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class UserManagementBean implements Serializable {
    // PRIVATE FIELDS
    private User user = new User();
    private List<UserGroup> groupsList;
    private Integer usergroup_id;

    // BEAN'S PUBLIC METHODS
    public void initializeGroupsList() {
        groupsList = loadAllGroupsFromDatabase();
        System.out.print(String.format("%d groups have been loaded\n", groupsList.size()));
    }

    // Getters, setters and database-loading code has been ommited
    ...
}
```

**Question is:** when/how should I initialize the list of user groups, which is used to populate the select element on the page?

First I tried to use an <f:event> element which calls **initializeGroupsList()** on the "**preRenderView**" event (as in the code I've wrote above). Everything is populated fine, but if I select a user group and do not type any username, the select element returns an error message after the form is submitted (**"Validation Error: Value is not valid"**), while it should not give me any validation errors, as the user has selected a valid user group.

Secondly, I have tried replacing the **<f:event>** by a **<f:viewAction>** which calls **initializeGroupsList()**. When I open the page for the first time, everything works fine. But when I submit the form without a username, the page is reloaded, showing me the validation error, and the select element is not populated with any user groups at all (the **initializeGroupsList()** isn't called at all when there are validation errors in this case).

Currently I'm solving this issue by removing both the **<f:event>** and **<f:viewAction>** elements, and annotationg **initializeGroupsList()** with **@PostConstruct**. Problem is: if I do so, I won't be abble to access any of the URL's query string parameters through the use of **<f:viewParam>** inside the **initializeGroupsList()**, which is something I want to be able to do in this page in a near future.

How should I call **initializeGroupsList()** then, to avoid these errors described in both the first and second cases, while allowing me to access URL's query string parameters inside **initializeGroupsList()**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Keep using @PostConstruct to initialize initializeGroupsList().

About the view params you could use @Param ( http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param ) from  ominifaces, which will inject them for you without the need to use view action or view event.